# filename encoding issue

Tags: php, encoding, ubuntu, utf-8, filenames

I am getting a file with a faroese name and trying to save it in a PHP script:

```
2010_08_Útflutningur.xls
```

In Ubuntu 10.04 LTS is saving it as :

```
2010_08_�tflutningur.xls (invalid encoding)
```

I've installed and run utf8-migration-tool, but with no effect.

Is this a ubuntu error that I can fix or I just have to give up and modify the name in php?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu uses UTF8 internally for its filenames. In this particular case [utf8_encode](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) does the trick as the original filename is ISO-8859-1 encoded. In other cases I could use [iconv](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php), and [detect the encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) if is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

"Ú" it's not the ubuntu error.Basically your "Ú" chartered takes as a unreadable special charecter.So it's better to modify the name.

Comment: PHP is reading it correctly and with proper encoding. why not saving it as it came? it was generated as a valid name for the original OS.